# updating an user's object in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a problem with updating an existing user object in my database. When I update and change the user object it saves and everything is looking ok but when I change the user and I want to login this user does not authenticate. Here is my code:

```
def profile_edit(request):
    user = request.user
    profile = request.user.profile

    context = {
        'user': user
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        user.profile.address = request.POST.get('address')
        user.profile.phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        user.set_password('password')
        user.username = username
        user.save()
        user.profile.save()
        authenticate(user)
        context = {
            'profile': profile
        }

        return render(request, 'helpdesk/profile.html', context)
    return render(request, 'helpdesk/profile_edit.html', context)
```

and login view:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            profile = request.user.profile
            context = {
                'profile': profile
            }

            return render(request, 'helpdesk/user_desk.html', context)
        else:
            context = {
                'username': username,
                'error': 'user not find!'
            }

    else:

        context = {}
        return render(request, 'helpdesk/login.html', context)
```

Comment: Hi arsalanhami, try to improve the english grammar. As I am not a english born either, I used to write my question in my own languange on Google Translator before ask here. You can get more responses.

Comment: yeahh i should .thank you @Josir

Answer (score 0):

When updating the password you are actually setting the string `'password'` as password and not the submitted password. Change `user.set_password('password')` to `user.set_password(password)` to correct this.

Comment: If you say that the authentication worked before you updated the profile and that the profile edit also seems to execute correctly, only your password update can be at fault here as it's the only field that's hard to verify. So if you updated your code with the suggestion in my answer then the issue is most likely with sending the password from the frontend to your backend. Can you include more code from that part?

Comment: i have post html you can see ,but when i edit a user object in auth_user i can see the changes but dosnt work

Answer (score 0):

```
<form  action="" style="font-size: 2cm" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="row" style="margin: 7px">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="first_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="username:{{ request.user.username }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="address" id="last_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="address:{{ request.user.address }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="email: {{ request.user.email }}">
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="password_confirmation" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="phone:{{ request.user.phone }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <input type="submit" value="EDIT" class="btn btn-info btn-block" style="background-color: #0d0d0d; border-color: #0d0d0d">

                    </form>
```